# How to find the maximum value of a column with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a table with 40 columns and 1500 rows. I want to find the maximum value among the 30-32nd (3 columns). How can it be done? I want to return the maximum value among these 3 columns and the index of dataframe.

```
print(Max_kVA_df.iloc[30:33].max())
```

[image]

Comment: Added beter sample data, which values should be filter? `6,3,1`? Or `3,1,8` ?

Comment: Thank you for the edit but I would want to know for the following headings. Though it might be same but I am new.

Answer (score 1):

Select values by positions and use `np.max`:

**Sample**: for maximum by first 5 rows:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  2  2  6
1  1  3  9
2  6  1  0
3  1  9  0
4  0  9  3

print (df.iloc[0:5])
   A  B  C
0  2  2  6
1  1  3  9
2  6  1  0
3  1  9  0
4  0  9  3

print (np.max(df.iloc[0:5].max()))
9
```

Comment: @AbanishTiwari - what return `print(Max_kVA_df.iloc[0:3,2])` ?

Comment: Maximum value in all of the three columns and the index!! I need those

Comment: is df=Max_kVA_df in my case?

Comment: @AbanishTiwari - yop, exactly

Comment: I need maximum value of the numbers of those 3 columns (not maximum of each column) when I did as in question it didn't displayed the maximum value and all the rows value before it.

Answer (score 1):

hi you can refer this example

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],
  'col2':[4,5,6,7,8],
  'col3':[2,3,4,5,7]
})

print(df)

#print(df.iloc[:,0:3].max())# Mention range of the columns which you want, In your case change 0:3 to 30:33, here  33 will be excluded
ser=df.iloc[:,0:3].max()
print(ser.max())
```

**Output**

```
8
```

Comment: what should I do to get maximum among the 3 columns, not in each column??

Comment: so in above example, if as far it is proper code what ouput you are expecting , example?

Comment: The maximum value is 8 in all of those columns, I need 8 and its index in dataframe i.e. 4 in this case. I my question the maximum value is 487 and the index is 17.

Comment: ser1=df.iloc[:,0:3].max()
    ser1.max()    #try this

Answer (score 0):

Or use `iloc` this way:

```
print(df.iloc[[30, 31], 2].max())
```